# How to inject dependencies into a FluentValidation AbstractValidator constructor, with Ninject and MVC4?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ninject, fluentvalidation

I'm using Ninject 3.0.1.10, MVC 5.0.0, FluentValidation 5.0 and finally FluentValidation MVC plugin library.

I'm trying to configure Ninject so that it injects a service into my `AbstractValidator` classes. I've read a lot of other answers about how to do this, but none have quite made sense to me. They all mention `AssemblyScanner`, which I can't find. They also mention accessing the `IKernal` from `App_Start`, but in my project `App_Start` does not have access to the `IKernal` because it's created inside of a `NinjectWebCommon.cs` file.

So I'm confused as to how to properly make this happen. Anybody have any clarity on this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the `IKernel` configured by `NinjectWebCommon.cs` anywhere in your application. Of course, this usually is not recommended since it's a smell of Service Locator anti-pattern.

But there are cases where we can't escape from it, specially when mixing the frameworks and in your composition root, it's ok.

So, wherever you need, just use:

```
using Ninject;

//My class that will need access to the IKernel
var kernel = (new Bootstrapper()).Kernel;
```

The `Bootstrapper` class is initialized in `App_Start.NinjectWebCommon` **before** even the `Application_OnStart` runs. So it is safe to use even in `Global.asax` to obtain a reference to the `IKernel`. It remembers the kernel instance that was provided to it via a *static variable* inside the [Bootstrapper](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject.Web.Common/blob/master/src/Ninject.Web.Common/Bootstrapper.cs#L34) class.

Hope that helps!